# MongoDB Stops Responding During Background Flush

Tags: mongodb

**Mongodb Background Flushing blocks all the requests:**

**Server:** Windows server 2008 R2

**CPU Usage:** 10 %

**Memory:** 64G, Used 7%, 250MB for Mongod

**Disk % Read/Write Time:** less than 5% (According to Perfmon)

**Mongodb Version:** 2.4.6

**Mongostat Normally**:

`insert:509 query:608 update:331 delete:*0 command:852|0 flushes:0 mapped:63.1g vsize:127g faults:6449 locked db:Radius:12.0%`

**Mongostat Before(maybe while) Flushing**:

`insert:1 query:4 update:3 delete:*0 command:7|0 flushes:0 mapped:63.1g vsize:127g faults:313 locked db:local:0.0%`

And **Mongostat After Flushing**:

`insert:1572 query:1849 update:1028 delete:*0 command:2673|0 flushes:1 mapped:63.1g vsize:127g faults:21065 locked db:.:99.0%`

As you see when flushes happening lock is 99% just at this point mongod stops responding any read/write operation (`mongotop` and `mongostat` also stop). The flushing takes about 7 to 8 seconds to complete which does not increase disk load more than 10%.

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Windows server 2008 R2 (and other versions of Windows I would suspect, although I don't know for sure), MongoDB's (2.4 and older) background flush process imposes a global lock, doing substantial blocking of reads and writes, and the length of the flush time tends to be proportional to the amount of memory MongoDB is using (both resident and system cache for memory-mapped files), even if very little actual write activity is going on. This is a phenomenon we ran into at our shop.

In one replica set where we were using MongoDB version 2.2.2, on a host with some 128 GBs of RAM, when most of the RAM was in use either as resident memory or as standby system cache, the flush time was reliably between 10 and 15 seconds under almost no load and could go as high as 30 to 40 seconds under load. This could cause Mongo to go into long pauses of unresponsiveness every minute. Our storage did not show signs of being stressed.

The basic problem, it seems, is that Windows handles flushing to memory-mapped files differently than Linux. Apparently, the process is synchronous under Windows and this has a number of side effects, although I don't understand the technical details well enough to comment.

MongoDb, Inc., is aware of this issue and is working on optimizations to address it. The problem is documented in a couple of tickets:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13444

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12401

What to do?

1. The phenomenon is tied, to some degree, to the minimum latency of the disk subsystem as measured under low stress, so you might try experimenting with faster disks, if you can. Some improvements have been reported with this approach.
2. A strategy that worked for us in some limited degree is avoiding provisioning too much RAM. It happened that we really didn't need 128 GBs of RAM, so by dialing back on the RAM, we were able to reduce the flush time. Naturally, that wouldn't work for everyone.
3. The latest versions of MongoDB (2.6.0 and later) seem to handle the
   situation better in that writes are still blocked during the long
   flush but reads are able to proceed.
4. If you are working with a sharded cluster, you could try dividing the RAM by putting multiple shards on the same host. We didn't try this ourselves, but it seems like it might have worked. On the other hand, careful design and testing would be highly recommended in any such scenario to avoid compromising performance and/or high availability
5. We tried playing with syncdelay. Reducing it didn't help (the long flush times just happened more frequently). Increasing it helped a little (there was more time between flushes to get work done), but increasing it too much can exacerbate the problem severely. We boosted the syncdelay to five minutes (300 seconds), at one point, and were rewarded with a background flush of 20 minutes.
6. Some optimizations are in the works at MongoDB, Inc. These may be available soon.
7. In our case, to relieve the pressure on the primary host, we periodically rebooted one of the secondaries (clearing all memory) and then failed over to it. Naturally, there is some performance hit due to re-caching, and I think this only worked for us because our workload is write-heavy. Moreover, this technique not in any sense a solution. But if high flush times are causing serious disruption, this may be one way to "reduce the fever" so to speak.
8. Consider running on Linux... :-)

Comment: 2.6.4 has improved this a lot:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13729
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13681
(other open server tickets still exit - at the time of this writing). Make sure this Windows hotfix is installed: http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/administration/production-notes/#install-hotfix-for-mongodb-2-6-6-and-later

Answer (score 0):

Background flush by default does not block read/write. mongod does flush every 60s, unless otherwise specified with -syncDelay parameter. syncDelay uses fsync() operation, which can set to block write while in-memory pages flush to disk. A blocked write could have potential to block reads as well. Read more: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/fsync/

However, normally a flush should not take more than 1000ms (1 second). If it does, it is likely the amount of data flushing to disk is too large for your disk to handle.

Solution: upgrade to a faster disk like SSD, or decrease flush interval (try 30s, rather than the default 60s).